# English word for "tablier" in the phrase "tablier de professeur ou d'enseignant"

Tags: translation

What is the English word for "tablier" in "tablier de professeur ou d'enseignant"?

Like this:

[image]

<sub>Source: [blouse-blanche.fr](https://www.blouse-blanche.fr/choisir-blouse-blanche/)</sub>

As worn by a doctor (physician), chemist or druggist.

Comment: Could you please expand your question: what is the meaning of the word "tablier"? What is the meaning of the whole phrase?

Comment: "Tablier", here, is that sort of special apron that any teacher wears in classroom and most of time is white.

Comment: In what countries is this worn? In the Anglo world teachers do not to the best of my knowledge conventionally wear any sort of 'apron', so we have no term for this. Perhaps if you could provide a picture we could suggest an appropriate translation.

Comment: "Tablier de professeur ou d'enseignant" is "Professor's or teacher's (apron??), Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, nowadays teachers don't wear them. But still, I do see ones wearing them in life or in TV.

Comment: Also it is like the one a doctor (physician), chemist or druggist wear.

Comment: Does it look like a "lab apron" or is it a white jacket with buttons?

Comment: Maybe it's largely decorative and symbolic, like 'masonic aprons' in Freemasonry?

Comment: I really thank you very much for the assistance you all provide me. I think I have found it. It is simply "lab coat." Again thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As covered in the comments, it is called a **lab coat** or **Doctors White Coat**.

Comment: Tanks a lot Brian Tompsett. This is what I was looking for.